# sanitizing html user inputs in php codeigniter

Tags: php, html

I have a user form where users can post comment on articles. i need to allow strong, em and span tags for user inputs. I know this can be achieved through strip_tags function but i also want the other tags not to stripped but be changed using say htmlspecialchars function so that  tags can be seen in the page.
I hope it made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Strip tags isn't safe](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison#striptags).  It'd allow a tag like `<strong onmouseover="alert('xss');">mouse over this lol</strong>` through.  Use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the prep_for_form validation rule found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference).  Additionally you probably want to use xss_clean.